# Wordpress Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: wordpress

this is my base tag:

```
<base href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/" />
```

it seems that this makes me some problems when I klick on a empty link or on an anchor.

[image]

my index.php in the theme folder looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <main id="index_main" class="maxWidth center">
                ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use a WordPress theme by visiting the files under `wp-content/themes/` folder. You activate the theme through the admin panel (Appearance > Themes), then the active theme is used through the main website, which you will find under `http://www.kwk.de/`.

WordPress loads theme files, theme files don't load WordPress.

You also probably don't want to use a `base` tag, as it may conflict with other WordPress code. Instead, use code like the following to access images, or use CSS background images.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/img.png" />
```

Comment: Stop using the `base` tag, and stop visiting the theme files directly. It's not how WordPress works.

Comment: but then I have problems with accessing my files in e.g. `theme/img/` with `img/img.png` e.g. in a css file

Comment: so everytime I want to reference a file in my html/php files I have to add this? it's a bit anoying...

Comment: @Simon Yes, but you could make a shorter function in `functions.php` if you want.